# Key Error when retriving values from a dictionary in a function even when the key exists

Tags: python

```
def country():
  country_url= 'https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/india'
  request = urllib.request.urlopen(country_url)
  result = json.loads(request.read())
  for values in result:
    print(values['currencies'])
    indian_currency= values['currencies']['INR']['name']    
    capital= values["capital"]
    for capital in values["capital"]:
      capital_city=capital
      continent= values["region"]
    
    print(f"The currency of India is the {indian_currency}, the capital city is {capital_city} and it is in the continent of {continent}.")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
    country()
  File "main.py", line 11, in country
    indian_currency= values['currencies']['INR']['name']    
    KeyError: 'INR'
```

I am trying to retrieve information about a country from an API by using a function. The indian_currency variable actually works and the value is printed from the dictionary in the fstring, but I am still getting a KeyError for the key "INR". I have already confirmed that it exists and the value would not print if it didn't so Im not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you show us what comes out of your `print(values['currencies'])` code?

Answer (score 0):

Well I have looked at the data. In one there is 'INR' in another there is 'USD'.

You should write an if/else statement.

```
if 'INR' in  values['currencies']:
    indian_currency= values['currencies']['INR']['name']
else:
    indian_currency = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Well in data, there are two keys INR and USD, you are trying to make a code which work for INR and not others. so for this once you got INR then you should process only that key and ignore other one.

so below is code with little fix

```
def country():
  country_url= 'https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/india'
  request = urllib.request.urlopen(country_url)

  result = json.loads(request.read())

  for values in result:
        print(values['currencies'])
        if "INR" in values['currencies']:
            indian_currency = values['currencies']['INR']['name']
            capital_city = values['capital'][0]
            continent = values['region']
            print(f"The currency of India is the {indian_currency}, the capital city is {capital_city} and it is in the continent of {continent}.")
```